# Adding two numbers which sum is greater than 255 in emu8086?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Hello i will need your help to fix up my code a little bit so can you help me with the following 
The task says
Write the first 15 words of the array
1,6,6,11,16,26, (every next number is for 1 less than the sum of the previous 2 numbers for example :16 = 6 + 11 - 1, 11 = 6+6-1, and so on and so on the next number is 16+26-1 = 41 ...)

My code works well but wont write in the array number bigger than 255, (when sum of the two numbers-1 is bigger than 255) How can i solve this ?
more cleary you can see the result on this picture https://ibb.co/g6gNsb
so **26+41 = 67 - 1 = 66** the number is okey but when **106 + 171 = 277 (number bigger than 255)** the next number is 20 WRONG the next number should be 276 and so one and so on

And here is my answer :

```
data segment

array dw 1,6,6,11,16,26,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
numberBefore dw 0
numberNow dw 0

ends                     

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)          
ends                   


code segment           

start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

; add your code here

    mov si,09d      ;to start from 26 
    mov cx,9d
    listing:
    mov dx,array[si]
    mov numberNow,dx

    sub si,2d       ;sub to to get the number before
    mov dx,array[si]
    mov numberBefore,dx

    mov ax,numberBefore
    add ax,numberNow
    sub ah,0001h    
    add si,4d      ;add 4 to get to the next slot
    ;the next number that needs to be in array
    mov array[si],ax


    loop listing


finish:
endp 

end start
```

it works until number bigger than 255 needs to be put in the array. 
Thank you very much

Comment: What do you think `sub ah,0001h` does? I am pretty sure you wanted `ax`.

Comment: did you read the task ? i sub one cause the next number in the array is sum of the previous two numbers -1 so sub ah,0001h substracts 1 from the result. 
@Jester

Comment: No, it doesn't. `ah` is the top 8 bits. It specifically subtracts the `100h` that you are missing.

Comment: how i need to solve that than ? i think you are wrong https://ibb.co/g6gNsb see here so 26+41 = 67 - 1 = 66 the number is okey but when 106 + 171 = 277 (number bigger than 255) the next number is 20 WRONG the next number should be 276 and so one and so on thats my problem @Jester

Comment: The `adc ax, 0` cleverly cancels that. No idea what you were smoking when you have written it :)  Just use `sub ax,1` as I told you okay? PS: that `adc` is just in your image, it's not in the code you posted.

Comment: I tried to add the carry i think carry was missing haha okey i sub ax,1 and deleted adc ax so my code looks https://pastebin.com/rTQcQKMT and it still doesn't work and work the same  @Jester

Comment: It still says `ah` ...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gSAhwF1s @Jester sub ax,1 and works worst as before

Comment: `mov si,09d` is wrong, you want `10`. Words begin on even addresses (0,2,4,6,8,10).

Comment: Thank you very much my friend this was the problem,thank you thank you!@Jester